# jQuery functions - re-invoking a self invoking function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that is I think is self invoked and I'm trying to figure out how to call it again.

This is how the function is declared:

```
 jQuery(function setupFormInputHandlers(){
     ...
 }
```

I try to put `setupFormInputHandlers()` in the developer tools console but I get an undefined error.

Answer (score 0):

See [jQuery document ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

```
// Passing a named function instead of an anonymous function.

function readyFn( jQuery ) {
    // Code to run when the document is ready.
}

$( document ).ready( readyFn );

//invoke again
readyFn()
```

Answer (score 0):

`$` is just used as alias to `jQuery` so when you say $('x') you mean jQuery('x')..the main function is overloaded to make it familiar and to allow working with ease... also what you are asking about the function (may be you missed pasting other part)

```
$(function(){}); or
jQuery(function(){});
```

both are methods of calling anonymous function shorthand for

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   //your code
}
);`
```

in simple words it means "When the document loading complete register your an anonymous function"

Comment: Ok so is the function I have pasted anonymous? Or should i be able to invoke it simply by `setupFormInputHandlers()` when i try to do this in the developer console I get a not defined error.

Comment: hey hi,well you have specified name to your function so its not anonymous (note syntax i mentioned)..also you wont be able to access it outside its scope ie `document.ready()`....whatever you put inside will be executed as  it is when the document is ready....